# LinkedIn Javascript SDK not redirecting back to page (iOS only)

Tags: javascript, ios, linkedin-api

I have a form in which you can apply with LinkedIn, it will give me some data in JSON format, I decode that and fill out the form.

Now this works for desktop browsers and Android devices this doesn't work however for iOS devices.

After you click the button, you can fill in the credentials, when you sign in and allow the use of information the window does nothing next, it doesn't go back to my website and doesn't fill out the form.

The funny part, like I said it doesn't work on iOS for Safari, Chrome, Firefox. It does work for Opera...

I have read that Apple let the page stop running Javascript as soon as it isn't active. But there has to be a work around or something for this right? Using the REST API didn't work out for me that well (because of the work I have done till now). I could start from scratch but rather not.

TL;DR: How do I redirect back to my website/page after a user has filled out his/her LinkedIn credentials.